# alert the class name of an element using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an element and i want to alert the class attribute of this element i use this code;

```
<li id="SSS" class="settings" onclick="alertClassName(this)">1111</li>
```

and in the alertClassName function ;

```
function changeClass(elem)
{
var x = $(elem.id);
alert(x.class) ;
}
```

it alerts undefind.

Comment: and i cannot use this code in the function that :" alert(elem.attr('class'))" should i use $ sign?and save it in a variable?

Comment: You seem to be using a library (otherwise, `$` has no meaning unless you've defined it to mean something). Which one are you using? jQuery? MooTools? Prototype?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `className` instead of `class`.

```
onclick="alertClassName(this)"
```

...

```
function alertClassName(elem) {
  alert(elem.className);
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className).

Comment: function changeClass(elem)
{
 var x = $(elem.id) ;
 alert(x.className);
} it downst work too

Comment: Well, are you using `changeClass` or `alertClassName` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access class name directly via `className` property (no need for jQuery, in this case):

```
function alertClassName(elem)
{
    alert(elem.className);
}
```

Comment: Generally I agree, but sometimes it's good to leave some place for research. Why? This is accually pretty basic question. I believe that answer for it could be found within 5 seconds (after opening search engine). The other thing is that my example is pretty self explanatory (I think). It says: `you can access class name of element by using className property`

Comment: Yet, I've added a short explanation.

Comment: @EmadHelmi indeed, though I think it'd be better to set `class` for your first `li` (in this example). Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtbh/6/)

Comment: @EmadHelmi for the background, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtbh/7/), problem lies in your CSS/HTML structure.

Comment: @walkhard: It's good of you to persist on this. (That's my +1, btw. If it weren't already there, I'd've added it by now.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm glad you understand my point. Thanks for +1, though I've been (again) downvoted with no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have to decide on a function name (`alertClassName` or `changeClass`). I'll use `alertClassName` as that matches the question title:

Here:

```
<li id="SSS" class="settings" onclick="alertClassName(this)">1111</li>
```

...you're passing a reference to the actual element into your function. The `this` within the code in an `onxyz` DOM0 handler attribute refers to the element the `onxyz` attribute is on.

This means you can just use it directly:

```
function alertClassName(elem)
{
    alert(elem.className);
}
```

And if you wanted to change it:

```
<li id="SSS" class="settings" onclick="changeClass(this, 'foo')">1111</li>
```

and

```
function changeClass(elem, newClass)
{
    elem.className = newClass;
}
```

...would remove all classes from the element when it was clicked and add the `foo` class.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to activate different function then what you posted) `alertClassName` instead of `changeClass` )

Here's an example of how to alert and then change the class of your element. (here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtbh/2/)).

And the code:

```
<li id="SSS" class="settings" onclick="changeClass(this)">1111</li>

<script>
function changeClass(e)
{
    alert("Current Class:" + e.className);
    e.className = "Settings2";
    alert("Updated Class:" + e.className);
}
</script>
```

Comment: but it doesnt change the background color. in my class which is named settings2 i change the font family and font size and the backhground color of the li tag but only the font change

Comment: You didn't define the classes in CSS. Here's a fiddle with defined classes so you can see the change. http://jsfiddle.net/yVtbh/3/

Comment: in my style sheet i have write .settings2 class; and the change the class to the settings2

Comment: drop the `class` word, see the fiddle

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
alert($(this).attr('class'))
```